# Using constructor to set values in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

My major intention is to do validation for an object in Spring Controller itself.
My code structure looks like

```
public @ResponseBody
String functionName(@RequestBody Employee employee){}
```

The idea is to validate the DTO the moment an http post request is hit

For same,I wrote an exception method to be called in constructor which adds the object to an error queue in case of error.

However the problem is, the values are set in spring by setter and not by constructor.

Is there any way/setting to change it so that values are set by constructor.

**EDIT**
The intention is to validate object employee the moment request is received without writing another method to validate.
My idea was to do validation in constructor of Employee and in case of failure, Pass the data to a error handler and stop object formation itself.
But it seems, In spring constructor is not used to set data, instead setter's are used.

So question is if constructor can be used.

Comment: I strongly believe that `public @ResponseBody
String functionName(@RequestBody <DTO> <dtoName>)` is not a constuctor and is also a syncatical wrong statment that will not even compile - please correct it and also clarify your question.

Comment: It this what you are asking for: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-constructor-injection

Comment: @Ralph , The code which I shared is part of a controller call. Which takes Employee object as an input. Spring Rest converts the JSON into the Employee object. However, while setting data into that object. It seems to be using setters, 
Is there any way to override that behavior and make spring use constructor instead ?

Comment: Your code looks like it for an Json Mapping. If you use jackson(FasterXML) for Json-Mapping, then you should look for an way to configure Jackson to use the constructor. have a look at this article http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html it looks like it solves your problem.